# Recursive Query SQL run too slow? how to improve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, recursive-query

I am running a recursive query to build a hierarchy path for parent-child relationship. Problem is  the query runs too slow. It takes 10hours and still not finish. My table EMPLOYEE has 40K rows. I am using  SQL Server

Original Table

| Employee | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| Luna | Jack |
| Japan | Jack |
| Alice | Luna |
| Alex | Luna |
| Jessica | Alex |

Here is my desired table with column  the path

| Employee | Manager | Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Null | Jack |
| Luna | Jack | Jack - Luna |
| Japan | Jack | Jack - Japan |
| Alice | Luna | Jack - Luna - Alice |
| Alex | Luna | Jack - Luna - Alex |
| Jessica | Alex | Jack - Luna - Alex - Jessica |

My query

```
With emp as (
    select
      Manager as Employee,
      cast(Null as varchar(max)) as Manger,
      cast(Manager as varchar(max)) as path
    from Employee e1

    union all 

    select
      e2.Employee,
      cast(Manager as varchar(max)) as Manger,
      cast((emp.path + '-' + e2.Employee) as varchar(max)) as path
    from employee e2
    join emp on e2.Manager = emp.Employee
)
select *
from emp
```

Any idea how to improve code efficiency?

Comment: First work out your RDBMS; SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different products.

Comment: Please read through this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557 which has a lot of good information on how to ask a SQL question here at Stack Overflow then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: table structure (with indexes), and query is needed to find out what is wrong

Comment: And 10 hours for 40K rows sounds like a blocking problem, not a plan cost problem.  Start by gathering the actual query plan in a test environment.

Comment: In your sample data `Jack` is not an employee

Comment: Use "execution plan" in SQL Server Management Studio. Example how to use [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan-in-sql-server?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Comment: Show us your execution plan using "Paste The Plan"

Comment: You can share the execution plan via https://pastetheplan.com. Please also show us the relevant table and index definitions. I'm guessing an index `(Manager, Employee)` is necessary

Comment: When I select actual execution plan, Error "Showplan permission denied in database"

Comment: There is no index number, the actualy key use to join is manager_name_id (like jack.123) and employee_name_id ( like Luna@102) . I modified to name for reading convinient

Answer (score 1):

Recursive CTEs are great to a point.   However, if you are looking to build a large hierarchy (like 200K+), there is **NO** shame in using TEMP tables.

Here is a stripped down/modified version I've used for my LARGE and SLOW MOVING hierarchies.

**Example**

```
Create Table #YourTable ([Employee] varchar(50),[Manager] varchar(50))
Insert Into #YourTable Values 
 ('Jack',null)
,('Luna','Jack')
,('Japan','Jack')
,('Alice','Luna')
,('Alex','Luna')
,('Jessica','Alex')


Select *
      ,Lvl=1
      ,Path=convert(varchar(500),Employee)
 Into  #TempBld 
 From  #YourTable 
 Where Manager is null

Declare @Cnt int=1
While @Cnt<=30  -- Set Max Level -- You can be a little generous here.
    Begin
        Insert Into #TempBld 
        Select A.*
              ,Lvl =B.Lvl+1
              ,Path=B.Path+' - '+A.Employee
         From  #YourTable A
         Join  #TempBld B on (B.Lvl=@Cnt and A.Manager=B.Employee)
        Set @Cnt=@Cnt+1
    End

Select * from #TempBld Order by Path
```

**Results**

```
Lvl Employee    Manager   Path
1   Jack        NULL      Jack
2   Japan       Jack      Jack - Japan
2   Luna        Jack      Jack - Luna
3   Alex        Luna      Jack - Luna - Alex
4   Jessica     Alex      Jack - Luna - Alex - Jessica
3   Alice       Luna      Jack - Luna - Alice
```

Comment: Thank John, problem is I cannot create new table, my role permission is connect & view data only